# Disable "Scan to computer has been deactivated"

Tags: windows-10, printer, scanner

I have a laptop which isn't always connected to the internet. I also have a printer driver which insists on always being connected to the printer, and if it's not, popping up a message that says something like "scan to printer has been deactivated". I can't tell exactly what it is because this message goes away before I have a chance to read it, and given that I have internet provided by a company which `[IRRELEVANT]`, it randomly disconnects -- the router, that is, not the outside connection -- throughout the day.

Now, I've called this internet company, and they've "fixed" their end of the problem (because we rent the router from them, they're supposed to keep it working). Since that channel failed, I've decided that the only way to stop myself from going crazy is disabling the notifications on my end. Unfortunately, I can't click on them, and they don't persist in the notification center, so I have no idea what's causing them.

I have an HP Photosmart 6520 with (what Windows assures me are) the latest drivers, Windows 10, and a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga. I'm almost certain the computer's specs are irrelevant, but I could add them if necessary.

**TL;DR**: How can I disable the notifications about scan to printer being disabled which pop up every time my awful router disconnects from my computer?

---

I'm sorry for the angry tone of this post. This is an issue that has been driving me up the wall for weeks now, and despite my best efforts I can never fix it. Please feel free to edit it to make it more neutral.

Comment: Might be worth checking this out [HP Forum](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/Scan-to-Computer-is-currently-unavailable-Message/td-p/1181923) it suggests that it requires a constant connection between your PC and your printer for this feature. An outside internet connection shouldn't affect that, unless it's combined with a greater issue caused by your router. There are a number of suggestions to try, but if you don't use that feature regularly it might just be easier preventing it from loading on startup. This can usually be done from the toolbar.

Comment: @Mark Whoops, I made a brain fart. Yeah, it's the whole router dying every time, or at least the routing. I'll fix that in the question now.

Comment: @Mark Also, their solution doesn't work, because the notification doesn't persist, at least not anywhere I can see.

Comment: If there isn't an option to prevent in from loading on startup in the toolbar (usually within the preferences for that application) You could always prevent it from starting up in the "startup" tab of your Task Manager (Right click -> disable)

Comment: @Mark Could you write that as an answer? I've set the option and now I'm going to bed, so if it works I'll accept tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually disable a program from running on startup by right clicking on the respective programs icon in the toolbar, or by opening the program and digging into the preferences or options for that program. It's generally a tick box labelled as "Launch at login" or "Start on system startup".

[image]

This can also be done in the Startup tab of the Task Manager by right clicking on the respective program and enabling / disabling it.

I would probably suggest finding it within the options / preferences of your application first before trying this.

With both of the above options you will have to manually run the HP scan software before you can scan, then exit from it once finished.

Also since I originally replied I discovered that you can disable notifications for applications individually through "Notification & actions" as per below. Assuming there is an option for your problem program this may be the best option.

[image]

There more than likely will be other options for your situation but these have usually resolved them for me.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this works. Thank you so much! (For the record, what I did was remove it from Startup via Task Manager -- there was no option for individual notifications, at least that I saw, on mine, and I couldn't find the checkbox you mentioned)